# How to access a variable in Program class (console app)

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I would like to know how to access a public var in `Program` class of the console app.

```
class Program
{
        public static string Name { get; set; }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Some code here       
        }
}

static class Settings
{
        static public void DoJob()
        {
            // Access Name of Program ?
        }
}
```

Comment: `Program.Name`, but something tells me you're not asking the right question.

Comment: @sstan Yes I am asking exactly this point. Do we have create a instance of Program? Or it will work like you said?

Comment: `Name` is `static`, so no instance is needed to access it.  But a static property the way you have it doesn't feel right, design-wise.  I guess we would have to better understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: @sstan I need to get arg and keep in the Progam.Name and access it later in any static class. Is it possible to do like I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can do this, But the `args` is a string array and the property `Name` is a string variable, So you need to assign one value from args to the Name. Or use [`String.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) to get all values to `Name` with a delimiter.

Since the Name is static variable no instance is needed to access the variable. You will get the value through  `Program.Name` in the static class. Now see the code:

In Main getting value from args to Name

```
public static string Name { get; set; }
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Name = args[0]; // taking the First value from the args array
    //or use String.Join to get all elements from args
    string delemitter = "";
    Name = String.Join(delemitter, args);
}
```

In Static class assign value of Name to a local variable:

```
static class Settings
{
    static public void DoJob()
    {
        string localVar = Program.Name;
    }
}
```